# Executing jar file with jars in folders

Tags: java, jar, classpath, manifest.mf

I am inside a E:/foo/bar folder inside windows environment. I have a jar file as E:/foo/bar/a.jar. Also inside foo/bar there are lot of jar files. Also under the foo/bar there is another directory called ext. It also includes lot of jar files.

I want to run the a.jar with those jars included in the class path(both current directory and ext directory). So I used this.

```
java -jar a.jar -classpath *:/ext/*
```

This didn't work. I didnt add any entries in the MANIFEST.MF in a.jar thinking that this will be fetched from the -classpath entry. What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `-classpath` option is ignored if `-jar` is specified.

Two possible course of action I can see:

1. Put a manifest in the main Jar that **does** specify the other Jars.
2. Specify the class-path at run-time.

   1. Drop the `-jar` option of the invocation.
   2. Specify all the dependent Jars
   3. Add the fully qualified class name to the end of the command, something like 
      `java -classpath *:/ext/* com.our.MainClass`

Comment: Thanks. Your 3) doesnt work. It throws Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test.test.MyClass

Comment: I'm not sure of the wild-card characters, I don't use them.  Try specifying the Jar with the main class explicitly in the class-path and see if the error message changes.

Comment: The issue is there are hundreds of jar files. And I dont know which is needed and which is not.

Comment: One that is needed is the one containing the main class.  Can you identify that one?  Note that my suggestion was *not* intended as a final solution (which would be found through my point 1. that you seem to be ignoring), it was just intended as a debugging aid to confirm if the wildcards had any effect as used.

Comment: I used the Main-Class and it was there when I test the above. Any other solution for this? As I heard java 6 and upwards it supports wildcards like this

Comment: What OS are you running on, and more specifically, what is the value of [`path.separator`](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=path.separator&format=TSV)?